# Parent-child relationship in many to many

Tags: database-design, many-to-many, parent-child

I'm trying to construct a parent-child relationship in SQL Server 2008 and I'm having trouble getting it to work.

1. There are Presets (root level nodes) and then there are PresetItems (child nodes).
2. A Preset can only contain PresetItems, but PresetItems can contain other PresetItems as child nodes.
3. Many Presets can be built that vary in the PresetItems that they contain.
4. The PresetItems can be reused in many different Presets to construct a different Preset configuration.

The way this is used is to dynamically create a report.  The Preset is the name of the report.  The PresetItems are various parts to the report.  These parts (PresetItem) would be like a section of the report, such as "Year to Date Graph". This PresetItem would contain the text explanation, and then another PresetItem containing the graph could be added as the child of this PresetItem section.

This process continues until all the parts of the report are assembled.

Here is an illustration:

```
Client "A" Report (Preset 1)
   -- Overview (PresetItem 1) - contains boilerplate and maybe some dynamic data
   -- YTD Report (PresetItem 2) - contains boilerplate
      -- YTD Graph (PresetItem 3) - contains a graph created dynamically from SQL Server data
   -- Core References (PresetItem 4) - contains a table of dynamic data
   -- Summary (PresetItem 5) - contains boilerplate

Client "B" Report (Preset 2)
   -- Overview (PresetItem 1) - contains boilerplate and maybe some dynamic data
   -- Monthly Balance Sheet (PresetItem 8) - contains dynamic data
   -- YTD Report (PresetItem 2) - contains boilerplate
      -- YTD Graph (PresetItem 3) - contains a graph created dynamically from SQL Server data
   -- Summary (PresetItem 5) - contains boilerplate
```

... etc ...

You'll notice that some PresetItems can be assembled into many different reports or Presets.

This is the way I've constructed my database tables and I'm not able to create the parent-child relationship because there are two primary keys in the many-to-many table.

```
Preset Table
-- Id (key)
-- Name

PresetItem Table
-- Id (key)
-- Name
-- Description
-- DataResource
-- (other columns)

PresetPresetItem (many-to-many table)
-- PresetId (key)
-- PresetItemId (key)
-- ParentId
-- SortOrder
```

Am I on the right track to get the result that I'm looking for?  I'm not able to create the parent-child relationship in the PresetPresetItem table between the PresetItemId and the ParentId, because it complains that I've left out the other primary key (PresetId).

I do understand why it's doing this, I just can't figure out how to fix it right now.  If I'm going about this all wrong, please let me know.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of ways to solve this.

Probably the simplest one is to split each "kind" of connection into separate table:

[image]

---

Alternatively, you could also consider inheriting the `Preset` and `Item` from the common table and then implementing the graph edges on top of *that* table. This might be too flexible for your needs, though: `Preset` could be a child of another `Preset` or even `Item`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: This is almost there I think.  This is good in the fact that the "Items" need to be independent of a Preset but Presets cannot be children of other Presets.  I think I need to investigate this a little more.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with SQL server, so I'm limiting my discussion here to database design.

It sounds to me like this is where you need to go:

If PresetItems can refer to themselves *in a strictly hierarchical fashion*, the third table is unnecessary.  In this case, just give PresetItems a foreign key back to itself.  If that's not the case, I'll have to think about how I would implement a many-to-many-to-self relationship.

But, if this assumption is were wrong, then you're probably on the right track!

Something like this:

```
Presets
-------
presetId (PK)

PresetItems
-----------
presetItemId (PK)
presetIdFk (FK to Presets)
presetItemIdFk (FK to PresetItems (self))
```

This allows one Preset to many PresetItems, and PresetItems will be organized as a tree.

If PresetItems don't represent hierarchical data, you should do something like this:

[Many-to-many self-referential table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133104/many-to-many-self-referential-table)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll give it a shot and see what happens.  BTW, I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Actually thinking about your suggestion again doesn't seem like it will work in this case.  Your suggestion will make the Preset contain only one PresetItem, and it needs to contain any number of presetitems. I created some temp tables and I wasn't able to create a SQL statement to return the results I needed.